# How to understand this syntax? var {...} = React;

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, react-native

in react native example:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native

```
var React = require('react-native');
var { ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, Text } = React;

var TouchDemo = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}>
          <Text>Proper Touch Handling</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  },
});
```

what is this syntax mean?

```
var { ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, Text } = React;
```

I typed it in nodejs console cause syntax error. Is this special Javascripts syntax only for React Native?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is an ES6 feature, but it may be a JSX-specific thing as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: See destructuring assignment [here](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/using-es6-harmony-with-nodejs#2-2-destructuring-assignment) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).  It's syntax sugar to save typing .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), an [ECMAScript 6 feature](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#destructuring). As far as I know it is not included in any version of node.js or iojs yet, but there may be a command line flag you can use to enable it.

Comment: Thank you. It is really handy. Like this feature since Python.

Answer (score 1):

[This document](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html) describes the JavaScript environment which is supported by React Native.

> ES5
>
> - Reserved Words: `promise.catch(function() { });`
>
> ES6
>
> - Arrow function: `<C onPress={() => this.setState({pressed: true})}`
> - Call spread: `Math.max(...array);`
> - Class: `class C extends React.Component { render() { return <View />; } }`
> - Destructuring: `var {isActive, style} = this.props;`
> - Iteration: `for (var element of array) { }`
> - Computed Properties: `var key = 'abc'; var obj = {[key]: 10};`
> - Object Consise Method: `var obj = { method() { return 10; } };`
> - Object Short Notation: `var name = 'vjeux'; var obj = { name };`
> - Rest Params: `function(type, ...args) { }`
> - Template: var who = 'world'; var str = `Hello ${who};`
>
> ES7
>
> - Object Spread: `var extended = { ...obj, a: 10 };`
> - Function Trailing Comma: `function f(a, b, c,) { }`